# Parsing Large XML (>4k) in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I am getting an xml of length around 30k. I have to extract key and value pairs from this xml and insert into a table. Also have to avoid from duplicated rows in table. Here is the query I came up with:

```
DECLARE
  PARSER XMLPARSER.PARSER;
  XMLDOC XMLDOM.DOMDOCUMENT;
  NODELIST XMLDOM.DOMNODELIST;
  REFDATA VARCHAR2(32767);
  REFDATAPART VARCHAR2(32767);
  NODELENGTH NUMBER;
```

BEGIN

```
  REFDATA := '<ReferenceFields><ReferenceField><FieldKey>Name1</FieldKey>                  <FieldValue>ABCD</FieldValue></ReferenceField><ReferenceField><FieldKey>Name1</FieldKey><FieldValue>ABCD</FieldValue></ReferenceField></ReferenceFields>';
  PARSER := XMLPARSER.NEWPARSER;
  XMLPARSER.PARSEBUFFER(PARSER,REFDATA);
  XMLDOC := XMLPARSER.GETDOCUMENT(PARSER);
  NODELIST := XMLDOM.GETELEMENTSBYTAGNAME(XMLDOC, 'ReferenceField');
  NODELENGTH := XMLDOM.GETLENGTH(NODELIST);
  FOR i IN 0..NODELENGTH-1 LOOP

    XMLDOM.WRITETOBUFFER(XMLDOM.ITEM(NODELIST, i),REFDATAPART);
    INSERT INTO 
        HTS_TRANSACTION_XREF(TRANS_ID,XREF_FIELD, XREF_VALUE) 
    SELECT 
        '1',
        EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE, '/ReferenceField/FieldKey') "FIELDKEY",
        EXTRACTVALUE(COLUMN_VALUE, '/ReferenceField/FieldValue') "FIELDVALUE"
    FROM 
        TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(REFDATAPART))) REFDATA
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from TRANSACTION_CROSSREFERENCE WHERE TRANS_ID='1' AND XREF_FIELD=EXTRACTVALUE(column_value, '/ReferenceField/FieldKey') AND XREF_VALUE=EXTRACTVALUE(column_value, '/ReferenceField/FieldValue'));

  END LOOP;

XMLPARSER.FREEPARSER(PARSER);
```

END;

This query works fine and finally would be part of sproc.

Here I have two questions:

1- Is this the right way to process large xml of maximum size 32k.

2- Will this be efficient enough to handle 700 calls in a second?

Thanks,
Attiq

Comment: "2- Will this be efficient enough to handle 700 calls in a second?" - what hardware is this running on, is anything else running on this, etc. this is a question only you can answer. Personally, I wouldn't do this kind of processing in the database, but would rather do it in an application server, which you can better ( and cheaper ) scale to meet your requirements.

Comment: You could also look at XMLTYPE, which in my opinion is easier to work with than the XMLPARSER. No idea if it will perform better or not. 32K should not pose a problem, but I have seen performance problems in XMLTYPE using XML of MBs in size. For 700 tps, I'd look at using a mid-tier app server to do the heavy XML lifting and compare the performance of both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you definitely want to gather the inserts at least. I don't know how big is NODELENGTH but you may use something similar to:

In your declare part:

```
TYPE T_STRING IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1024); -- adjust size
arr T_STRING    := T_STRING();
```

in the pl body:

```
REFDATA         := '<ReferenceFields><ReferenceField><FieldKey>Name1</FieldKey>                  <FieldValue>ABCD</FieldValue></ReferenceField><ReferenceField><FieldKey>Name1</FieldKey><FieldValue>ABCD</FieldValue></ReferenceField></ReferenceFields>';
PARSER          := XMLPARSER.NEWPARSER;
XMLPARSER.PARSEBUFFER(PARSER,REFDATA);
XMLDOC          := XMLPARSER.GETDOCUMENT(PARSER);
NODELIST        := XMLDOM.GETELEMENTSBYTAGNAME(XMLDOC, 'ReferenceField');
NODELENGTH      := XMLDOM.GETLENGTH(NODELIST);


FOR i IN 0..NODELENGTH-1 LOOP
    XMLDOM.WRITETOBUFFER(XMLDOM.ITEM(NODELIST, i), REFDATAPART);
    arr.EXTEND();
    arr(arr.COUNT) := XMLSequence(XMLTYPE(REFDATAPART));
END LOOP;

FORALL i IN arr.FIRST..arr.LAST
    INSERT INTO HTS_TRANSACTION_XREF(TRANS_ID,XREF_FIELD, XREF_VALUE)       
        SELECT 
            '1',
            EXTRACTVALUE(arr(i), '/ReferenceField/FieldKey') "FIELDKEY",
            EXTRACTVALUE(arr(i), '/ReferenceField/FieldValue') "FIELDVALUE"
        FROM 
            dual
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM TRANSACTION_CROSSREFERENCE 
                WHERE 
                    TRANS_ID   = '1' 
                AND XREF_FIELD = EXTRACTVALUE(arr(i), '/ReferenceField/FieldKey') 
                AND XREF_VALUE = EXTRACTVALUE(arr(i), '/ReferenceField/FieldValue')
            );


XMLPARSER.FREEPARSER(PARSER);
```

I also don't know what is the purpose of the not exists part, are you sure this is necessary?